# Evaluate string expression in kotlin without using script engine

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, expression

I want to evaluate the string expression without using script engine:

string expression can be like:

> "((true&&(!false)||true)&&true)&&true"

Anybody have any idea how this can be done in android using kotlin

Thanks

Comment: the string will contain ONLY `true`, `false`, `&&`, `||`, `!` and `()`? If yes, then you could write a simple program with stack to solve this. It's similar to "balance parentheses" problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes it will only contain true, false, &&, ||, ! and ().

Answer (score 3):

### **Kotlin Android**

---

##### app.gradle file

Add a new dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'
}
```

##### main.kt file

```
    var value = TextView.text.toString()
    var result = ExpressionBuilder(value).build().evaluate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer will not help you in your case where your string expression contain true, false, &&, ||, ! and (). BUT for those who wants to evaluate mathematical expressions I found [this library](https://github.com/RotBolt/KParser) that handles almost all mathematical operators.

Add it to your project and use it this way

```
    // In root build.gradle
    repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kaendagger/KParser"
          }
    } 

    //Add in the dependencies
    dependencies{
     implementation 'io.kaen.dagger:KParser-jvm:0.1.1'
    }
```

And then in your code you can do something like this

```
val parser = ExpressionParser()
val result = parser.evaluate("5+1+cos(PI)-2*2/4")
println(result)
```